# Программа проверяет двумерный массив на повторения элиментов в строке и столбце (как судоку) , Пока программа работает не для всех случаев

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;




public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int r = sc.nextInt();
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        int array[][] = new int[r][c];
        int p = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {


                array[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                for (int g = i ; g < r; g++) {
                    for (int v = j; v < c; v++) {

                        if (array[g][v] != array[i][j]) {

                            p = 1;
                        } else if (i != g && j != v)   {
                            p = 0;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (p == 0) {
            System.out.println(false);
        } else if(p==1) {
            System.out.println(true);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что хотелось получить?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov  True tесли не повторяються и False если повторяються

Comment: Что повторятся? Как повторяется? Все равны или есть равные?

Comment: Ну так у вас если находятся повторяющиеся элементы, а далее встречаются не повторяющиеся, то `p` становится равным 1 опять. Может вам нужно `break` делать, в случае если нашли повторяющиеся?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov  в каждой строке и столбце не повторяюшиесь элементы, как в судоку ( так в масииве могут встречаться элементы,что повторяються

Comment: @iksuy Разве это влияет на условие ?

Comment: Т.е. если хотя бы в одной строке или хотя бы в одном столбце есть одинаковые элементы, то вернуть true, иначе false. Так?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov принцип такой только наоборот с True и False